# how to solve "Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug"

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I was trying to run my Flutter app and this shows up:

I do flutter clean, I delete pubspec.lock

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/mac/development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1005
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/Users/mac/development/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Run "flutter doctor" in the terminal and send the output.

Comment: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.0, on macOS 11.5.2 20G95 darwin-x64, locale en-FR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.59.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!

Comment: Create a new flutter project and copy only the lib folder from the old project to the new project. Add dependencies if previously used.

Comment: i do it but nothing. I got this problem just today when I upgrade flutter to the new version 2.5

Comment: Do you face the same problem if you run the demo project provided by flutter?

Comment: no its work with the demo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236990/discussion-between-priyansu-choudhury-and-user1232634).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you missed running pub get after running flutter clean. Build task issues similar to what you've encountered could be usually solved by running `flutter clean` to clear the project's build cache and running `flutter pub get` to fetch the project's dependencies configured in the project's pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Delete `android/app/build` folder and run `flutter clean`

worked for me.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the pubsec.lock file and run the project, it worked for me ;)